# Decrypting with gnupg just halts and does not work

Tags: terminal, encryption, gpg

I couldn't find a solution to this: I cannot decrypt my precious files anymore (on my main computer). I am using `pass` which relies on `gnupg`. Trying to decrypt a file just halts and doesn't give any result.

macOS 13.5.1 <-- Just recently upgraded, this might be the cause? *sigh*
gnupg via homebrew, I tried: 2.4.3 (latest)/2.4.2/2.4.1

Tried with/without pinentry-mac

```
# gpg-agent.conf
pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac
```

Example:

```
$ gpg --debug-level guru --decrypt __FILE__.gpg                                                                     

gpg: enabled debug flags: packet mpi crypto filter iobuf memory cache memstat trust hashing ipc clock lookup extprog
gpg: enabled compatibility flags:
gpg: DBG: [no clock] start
gpg: DBG: fd_cache_open (__FILE__.gpg) not cached
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: open '__FILE__.gpg' desc=file_filter(fd) fd=3
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: buffer size: 65536; still buffered: 0 => space for 65536 bytes
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: underflow: A->FILTER (65536 bytes)
gpg: DBG: iobuf-1.0: A->FILTER() returned rc=0 (ok), read 641 bytes
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=1 length=524 (parse.../../g10/mainproc.c.1641)
gpg: public key is __KEY__
gpg: DBG: free_packet() type=1
gpg: DBG: parse_packet(iob=1): type=18 length=112 (new_ctb) (parse.../../g10/mainproc.c.1641)

 .... nothing is happening here ....

^C
gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting
```

Does someone have a hint as to where to look, and what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing macgpg/gpgtools.org (https://gpgtools.org/) again. Though, this package via Homebrew: `brew install gpg-suite-no-mail`. *It works*.

It is a solution, but I don't want to accept this as the answer for now, because I'd like to have it work with the plain gpg binaries.
At the same time I believe apple just broke something again so there might be no solution as long it is not fixed in gpg or macOS.